# Serializing Maybe types

Tags: haskell, fay

What is the correct type for serializing `Maybe` types?

Given I have some data structure of `Maybe` type on the server and I serialize it with `showToFay` function, then it won't become one of the `{"instance":"Nothing"}` or `{"instance":"Maybe","slot1":<actual_value>}`, but it is serialized as either `null` or bare inside of the `Just`. Then it's not possible for me to deserialize it on the client correctly.

I'm using the `data MyMaybe a = MyNothing | MyJust a` type for now, but it's hard to do with as I need to pattern match all the time and I can't use the combinators defined on `Maybe`.

Comment: Unfortunate, sounds like a bug or misfeature.

Comment: I wouldn't say there is some correct type for serializing `Maybe a`. You could use aeson to read and write a `Maybe a` to/from JSON, provided you know how to read and write `a` to/from JSON. Or, you could use binary serialization from the cereal package. Both of these packages will work seamlessly with `Maybe a` provided `a` has the relevant instances defined. As far as I can tell, `showToFay` is for converting a Haskell value into something that a JavaScript interpreter could `eval()`. I don't think it's intended for serialization.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you know the type on both ends, this misfeature only makes deserialization impossible if you have something like `Maybe (Maybe T)`, since then you can't discriminate between `Nothing` and `Just Nothing`.

Comment: need to pattern match all the time - perhaps not, you can write instances for Monad, MonadPlus, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderVieth I think you could turn your comment into an answer -- it is very much to the point.